# Invalid option specified in CREATE INDEX statement

Tags: c#, sql, indexing, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to create a table which should ignore any duplicate value, using SQLCE. To do this, I figured I would select a column to be the index and use the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`option. When I run the code below:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX url_index ON Person (url ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON)
```

I get an error message saying "Invalid option specified in CREATE INDEX statement. [option name = IGNORE_DUP_KEY]."

Is this because I'm using SQLCE? If so, how can I ignore duplicates in SQLCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only valid with statement for [CREATE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345331%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) in SQL Server CE is `STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE`.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in CE. However, you are just creating an index, not a unique index, so you don't have to worry about duplicates.

Comment: It was originally unique, but I thought that it was the 'unique' aspect causing the error. I need the index to be unique and so if a duplicate is inserted, it should be ignored.

Comment: @Skoder: I'm afraid that your only option in this case is to add SQL to test for this condition and not perform the insert or update if the specified value already exists in this column (or clear the value, depending on the biz logic).

Comment: Thanks, I'll move the check directly in the SQL statements.